# Testing what happens when Google Play Services isn't available

Tags: android, google-play-services

Per the Google Play Services documentation I have a method that checks whether Google Play Services is available, and if available attempts to conncect. If the connection fails there is another method to deal with resolution.

Unfortunately, I have no way to test whether these methods actually work as it seems impossible to uninstall, disable, or rollback Google Play Services on my devices. What can I do to check these methods?

Answer (score 1):

Try it on a Amazon kindle device. They don't have Google Play Services installed by default.

Create a new Virtual Device from Android Virtual Device Manager and make sure to pick which does not say "(Google Inc.)" in it. With the google libraries, it will not have Google Play Store installed.

```
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getSupportActivity());
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Available");
        return true;
    } else {
        // Display an error dialog
        Log.d(TAG, "Unavailable");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I can't afford to buy a device just to test this app unfortunately.

Comment: See comment on other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can test on emulator. Emulator doesn't have GooglePlayServices

Speaking about emulators - [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is a good replacement for Android emulator coming with SDK, but it doesn't really matter which one to use - neither of them have PlayServices :)

Comment: You can't really test everything using the emulator, it just shows the dialog that says "Google Play Services not available on your device, sorry". Can't test the other resolutions or failure to connect to services.

Comment: If you need to test different play services errors why can't you just mock `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` function to return all different error codes specified in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))?

Answer (score 0):

You can [intercept the wifi traffic](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforandroid/) through Fiddler2, and mess with the data it's getting back from Google Play.

Note that carriers like AT&T also give you access to a [free tool](https://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer) to simulate wireless networks. I haven't actually tried it out yet, so please let us know if that tool is any good.